# Informix stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

When creating a stored procedure in Informix, it does not throw an error even if the related table does not exist..

I guess the reporting level is pretty high so how can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

That is the way Informix is designed to work.

If, when you run the procedure, the table still does not exist, then you will get a more or less appropriate runtime error.  But the mere fact that a table does not exist at the time the procedure is created is quite deliberately not viewed as an error; the table may be created by the time the procedure is used.

There is no setting that I know of to change this behaviour.

Comment: hey..thx for the reply..but the same proc when created in dev and prod envirornments behaves differently..stargely on dev no error is thrown but on prod an error is thrown..(the error is 591..default status of a column)..any idea abt this ? also when I do "info columns for table_name" for a table that does not exist,on dev I get blank column_type ...as a response without any error but on prod I get proper error message saying the table_name does not exists

Comment: look slike 11_70 onwards acually does some validation on table name when the procs are created.

Comment: I don't believe that any table name validation is possible. In Informix it is quite common to drop and create temporary tables within the procedure. It is perfectly valid. While database parses the procedure and encounters unknown table name then it can't raise exception because of possibility that the table was created few lines earlier. Table creation block may be placed in conditional block or even within a loop which makes static analisys impossible.